# Dynamic Programming Implementation in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem

[image]

This is the Python code and I am having trouble figuring out dp[i][j]. This is supposed to be the minimum cost for the first j city centers with i shops.

```
# A an integer array for city centers
# k an integer number of shops
# return  an integer
def groceryShops(A, k):
    # Write your code here
    if not A:
        return 0

    n = len(A) # n is the number of city centers.

    if k >= n: # we should not have more shops than city centers.
        return 0

    A.sort()
    cost = [[0 for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]

    """
    cost[i][j] is the minimum cost to build a shop between city centers i and j
    This shop should be in the median of the city centers.
    """
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            mid = int(i + (j - i) / 2)
            print("i= ", i, " j= ", j, "Median is: ", mid, " Center:",  A[mid], "\n")

            for r in range(i, mid + 1):
                cost[i + 1][j + 1] += A[mid] - A[r]
                print("dist of ", A[mid] ," --to-> " ,  A[r], " Right ", cost[i + 1][j + 1])
            for r in range(mid + 1, j + 1):
                cost[i + 1][j + 1] += A[r] - A[mid]
                print("dist of ",  A[mid] ," <--to-- " ,  A[r], " Left ", cost[i + 1][j + 1])
            print("COST: ", "(", A[i ], "," ,A[j], " )", cost[i + 1][j + 1], "\n\n")


    # print("cost")
    # for row in cost:
    #   for c in row:
    #     print(c, end = " ")
    #   print()
    """
    dp[i][j] is the minimum cost for the first j city centers with i shops.
    """
    dp = [[float('inf') for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(k + 1)]
    dp[0][0] = 0

    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            for r in range(j):
                dp[i][j] = ???  # only fill this gap :), min or max of some values using i, j and r?

    # print("\n\nDP Table")
    # for row in dp:
    #   for c in row:
    #     print(c, end = "       ")
    #   print("\n")

    return dp[-1][-1]
```

The following input `k = 5, a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 21, 40, 50]` should produce an output of 9.

Comment: Woah, you have to do this. We're glad to help on a specific problem after you do it, if it doesn't work, but not debug the whole thing, and not write it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KennyOstrom I didn't ask to debug the entire code. I just need to fill in one gap, as I have rewritten the Python code. All I need is that along with finding out the number of subproblems and the time complexity of the code itself

Comment: 'All I need' are things you should do yourself as part of the assignment.

Comment: @balmy I've figured how many subproblems there are, but I'm still having difficulty figuring out what the minimum cost for the first j city centers with i shops is supposed to be.

Comment: I see that there's just the one place where you left code blank, but it's not really ready for a question until you give it a go, and determine that's where the incorrect value is being computed. I'd suggest that computing dp[i] should probably depend on dp[i-1], if you're building up from a simpler subcase.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kenny Ostrom said, you have to get into the code by actually going through the debugger and checking your data structures while you do that and compare it with the actual task you wanted it to do.

Although, I did read the code and the time complexity is O(nk) :)